# double but different display clauses

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface

I found a great HOWTO (I would say) about an all CSS drop down menu here: [Create Vimeo-like top navigation](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/01/19/Create-Vimeo-like-top-navigation.aspx).

looking through the CSS I was confused over the rule

```
#menu ul { 
    padding:0px; 
    margin:0px; 
    display:block; 
    display:inline;
}
```

anyone able to explain what the double but different display clauses do?

cheers

Comment: I think that's a mistake

Comment: damn, I thought it was a new cool trick :) thanks